# Error Code: 403 Message: The caller does not have permission

Tags: python, api, google-api, http-status-code-403, google-classroom

I have a python script that from the spreadsheet it already creates the user on google and already inserts in certain classes in the classroom.

More when I run the script it creates the user correctly, but when inserting in the first class it gives the error `403 Message: The caller does not have permission`, when it goes to the second class it already inserts correctly. I've done several tests, the authentications are all right, I've tried with different classes and the error still persists.

can someone help me ? thanks

Comment: Hi ! What do you mean by ```it already creates the user on google``` ? What are you exactly trying to achieve? To add students to a Google classroom class? Also please provide any sample code *without any sensitive data* and if you can include your authentification piece of code (again without providing any sensitive data). Thanks ! :D

Comment: Hi! yes, it already creates the user on google! I solved it, the problem is actually in the propagation time of the new user, apparently when you create a new email it has a few seconds for it to work, so because of that it gave the permission error, as I'm using python when I get this error I use sleep() to pause the process, then everything continues correctly